# linux cat: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, grep, cat, printf

I have a peculiar problem in Linux2.4, C and using gcc.

There is a small program to retrieve information from a file using cat & grep cmd.

```
#define tmpFile "/tmp/cli_tmp_file.txt"
#define MAX_CMD 50

void getRange()
{
        char cmd[MAX_CMD+1];

        // remove the temp file first
        snprintf(cmd, MAX_CMD, "rm -f %s", tmpFile);
        system(cmd);
        // create temp file
        snprintf(cmd, MAX_CMD, "touch %s",tmpFile);
        system(cmd);
        // execute the command
        snprintf(cmd, MAX_CMD, "echo \"Range:Max val 500\" > %s",tmpFile);
        system(cmd);
        // dump out the temp file so user could see
        snprintf(cmd, MAX_CMD, "cat %s|grep \"Range\"", tmpFile);
        system(cmd);
        // remove the temp file
        snprintf(cmd, MAX_CMD, "rm -f %s", tmpFile);
        system(cmd);
}
```

when i execute this code, i get output as
cat: /tmp/cli_tmp_file.txt: No such file or directory

However, the file is created in the tmp folder with the contents

```
# pwd
/tmp
# ls -l
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           68 Oct 10 12:54 cli_tmp_file.txt

#more /tmp/cli_tmp_file.txt
Range:Max val 500
```

On manual execution of the same cmd, it displays the intended output

```
# cat /tmp/cli_tmp_file.txt|grep Range
Range:Max val 500
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check the return value of `system` to see if the commands succeed. Also, try printing the `cmd` buffer after each `snprintf` to see if it contains the intended command.

Comment: remove the file, try again.

Comment: Avoid using `system` with `rm`; consider calling [remove(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html) function. And to create a file, just `fopen` it for writing and `fclose` it just after. Don't forget to test against failure of every function.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just writing this as a shell script? It would be a bit simpler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a (managed, but ignored) buffer overrun, the `echo` command is more than 50 characters. The command is truncated by `snprintf()` but you run it anyway. Check return values!

Comment: it's doesn't seem to be more in his example. but definitely dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, adding sleep of 1 sec after touch resolved this issue.